# Como fazer uma regra de dias Uteis no Asp.net e C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

boa tarde
Eu estou querendo criar uma regra de envio de e-mail de cobrança que quando tem um feriado ele considera o dia seguinte e se for domingo ele realiza a tarefa na terça.
Hoje o sistema usa um banco onde ele checa os Clientes que esta com a situação de conta a receber em aberto e nosso sistema em ERP e envia um um e-mail de aviso após um determinado tempo de dias de atraso, porem nos dias que caem em feriados eu queria acrescentar mais um dia para não gerar a cobrança nele.

Eu estou utilizando um código que eu peguei em um fórum porem ele não carrega as datas como true ou false

```
 public static class testeferiado
    {
        public static DateTime Holiday(DateTime data)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Feriado(data))
                {

                    if (data.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    {
                        data = data.AddDays(2);
                    }
                    data = data.AddDays(1);
                    return Holiday(data);
                }


                return data;
            }
        }

        readonly static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        static string result;
        public static bool Feriado(DateTime dt)
        {

            command.CommandText = "select * from [mia].dbo.feriado where dtferiado = '" + dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";

            con.Open();

            command.Connection = con;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

E depois um código para realizar a checagem, onde utilizo o Quartz e nesse momento não consigo fazer ele entender o dia no CheckHelper.Holiday(),

```
  public class ScheduleHelper : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {

            //Delimita o tempo de execução até às 18h
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 18)
            {
                if (DateTime.Today == CheckHelper.Holiday())
                {


                    //Se horário é = 12h aplica-se a régua do setor financeiro
                    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 55)
                    {


                        //Se o dia da semana for = terça feira é necessário checar envios agendados
                        if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                        {
                            CheckHelper.CheckEnviosAgendados();
                        }

                        CheckHelper.CheckReguaFiananceiro();


                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eu implementei algo muito parecido com o que você quer. Tenho um método para pegar o próximo dia útil de uma determinada data. Segue o código:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Pega o próximo dia útil da data informada. Considera feriados nacionais.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime GetNextDiaUtil(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(2);
                else if (dateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);

                //if (dateTime.Day == 31 && dateTime.Month == 12) //----- Feriado bancário
                //    dateTime.AddDays(1);

                var publicHolidays = DateSystem.GetPublicHoliday(dateTime, dateTime, CountryCode.BR);

                if (publicHolidays.Count() > 0)
                    dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);
                else
                    return dateTime;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            throw new Exception("Buscar próximo dia útil", E);
        }
    }
```

Acima você observa um método que trata a questão dos feriados(`DateSystem.GetPublicHoliday`), eu utilizo o [Nager.Date](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Date/) que já faz isso pra gente. Você pode baixá-lo pelo nuget. Com isso eu não utilizo mais os feriados salvos no banco de dados.

Espero que tenha te ajudado.

Comment: Acredito que sua dica vai me ajudar bastante, porem eu deixo um log no banco para enviar no dia seguinte

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static List<Cliente> CheckRCEmail(string empresa, string data)
        {
            List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
            LeadLoversAPI llapi = new LeadLoversAPI();

            var ano = DateTime.Now.Year;


            var contasReceber = api.ListaContasReceber(empresa, "aberto", data, data);

            foreach (var item in contasReceber)
            {
                var pre_cliente = api.ObterContaReceber(item.id_conta_tiny, empresa).cliente;
                string cnpj_cliente = "";

                if (pre_cliente != null)
                {
                    cnpj_cliente = pre_cliente.cpf_cnpj;
                }

                var cliente = api.PesquisaPessoaByCnpj(cnpj_cliente, empresa);
                cliente.contatos = new List<Contato>();

                //Pega o contato financeiro, caso exista
                cliente.contatos.Add(api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Financeiro"));
                if (cliente.contatos[0] == null)
                {
                    //Pega o contato Proprietário, caso exista
                    cliente.contatos[0] = (api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Proprietario"));
                    if (cliente.contatos[0] == null)
                    {
                        //Pega o contato Proprietaria, caso exista
                        cliente.contatos[0] = (api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Proprietaria"));
                    }
                }

                if (cliente.contatos != null)
                {
                    if (cliente.contatos[0] != null)
                    {
                        LogFinanceiro log;
                        //Gravação de Log
                        log = new LogFinanceiro();
                        log.nome_cliente = cliente.nome;
                        log.contato_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].nome;
                        log.celular_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].celularddd + cliente.contatos[0].celularnumero;
                        log.email_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].email;
                        log.tipo_envio = "E-mail";
                        log.data_acao = DateTime.Now;
                        log.conta_receber_id = item.id_conta_tiny;
                        log.data_agendamento = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900");

                         /*Variavel do NuGet Nager.Date, biblioteca trabalha com feriado Fixos e que são alterados de acordo com o ano,
                     porem somente com feriados Federais*/

                    var publicHolidays = DateSystem.GetPublicHoliday(ano, "BR") ;

                    if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    {
                        log.data_agendamento = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
                        cliente.nome += " (agendado)";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                        {
                            log.data_agendamento = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                            cliente.nome += " (agendado)";
                        }
                        if (publicHolidays.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            log.data_agendamento = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                            cliente.nome += " (agendado)";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            llapi.InsertLead(cliente.contatos[0], new Maquina() { MachineCode = "278620", MachineName = "Regua de cobranca" });
                        }

                        }                                    
                        db.LogFinanceiroes.Add(log);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //Adicionao o cliente à lista de clientes enviados ao LeadLovers
                        clientes.Add(cliente);
                    }
                }

            }

            return clientes;
        }
```

ele esta assim agora

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static List<Cliente> CheckRCEmail(string empresa, string data)
    {
        List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
        LeadLoversAPI llapi = new LeadLoversAPI();

        var contasReceber = api.ListaContasReceber(empresa, "aberto", data, data);

        foreach (var item in contasReceber)
        {
            var pre_cliente = api.ObterContaReceber(item.id_conta_tiny, empresa).cliente;
            string cnpj_cliente = "";

            if (pre_cliente != null)
            {
                cnpj_cliente = pre_cliente.cpf_cnpj;
            }

            var cliente = api.PesquisaPessoaByCnpj(cnpj_cliente, empresa);
            cliente.contatos = new List<Contato>();

            //Pega o contato financeiro, caso exista
            cliente.contatos.Add(api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Financeiro"));
            if (cliente.contatos[0] == null)
            {
                //Pega o contato Proprietário, caso exista
                cliente.contatos[0] = (api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Proprietario"));
                if (cliente.contatos[0] == null)
                {
                    //Pega o contato Proprietaria, caso exista
                    cliente.contatos[0] = (api.ObterPessoa(cliente.id_cliente_tiny, empresa, "Proprietaria"));
                }
            }

            if (cliente.contatos != null)
            {
                if (cliente.contatos[0] != null)
                {
                    LogFinanceiro log;
                    //Gravação de Log
                    log = new LogFinanceiro();
                    log.nome_cliente = cliente.nome;
                    log.contato_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].nome;
                    log.celular_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].celularddd + cliente.contatos[0].celularnumero;
                    log.email_cliente = cliente.contatos[0].email;
                    log.tipo_envio = "E-mail";
                    log.data_acao = DateTime.Now;
                    log.conta_receber_id = item.id_conta_tiny;
                    log.data_agendamento = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900");





                    if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        {
                            log.data_agendamento = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
                            cliente.nome += " (agendado)";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                            {
                                log.data_agendamento = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                                cliente.nome += " (agendado)";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                llapi.InsertLead(cliente.contatos[0], new Maquina() { MachineCode = "278620", MachineName = "Regua de cobranca" });
                            }
                        }



                    db.LogFinanceiroes.Add(log);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    //Adicionao o cliente à lista de clientes enviados ao LeadLovers
                    clientes.Add(cliente);
                }
            }

        }

        return clientes;
    }
```

Para inserir o

```
var publicHolidays = DateSystem.GetPublicHoliday(dateTime, dateTime, CountryCode.BR);

                if (publicHolidays.Count() > 0)
                    dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);`
```

Vou precisar adapta-lo para fazer o log no banco, pois são e-mail de financeiro e não pode ser enviados em dias de feriados.
Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu adaptei porem ele quando ele vê os feriados, mesmo sendo 10/07/2019, ele add um dia